# Need to containing div to repeat in Angular4

Tags: angular

I need to separate div based on condition. Every 2 divs (col-md-4) have one parent div (col-md-12). This ngfor loops 2 times. I tried several ways but I did not find a solution.

**My Code**

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div *ngFor="let prop of objectProps; let index = index" class="col-md-4">
      <div [ngSwitch]="prop.type" class="ticket_fields">
         <div *ngSwitchCase="'Text box'">
            <input [name]="prop.key" [id]="prop.key" type="text" ngModel #prop.key="ngModel" *ngIf="(prop.required ==1)" required>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'Text area'">
            <textarea name="{{prop.key}}" [id]="prop.key" ngModel #prop.key="ngModel" *ngIf="(prop.required ==1)" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output**

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**But expected result i need**

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-4" >
       <input type="text"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4" >
       <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <input type="text"/>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-4" >
       <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the outer div inside ngFor?

Comment: yes, tried it returns the same result.

Comment: Have you tried <ng-container *ngFor="let prop of objectProps; let index = index"> your divs</ng-container>

Comment: Have you tried this ?

<div class="row col-md-12" *ngFor="let prop of objectProps; let index = index">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of code I would multiply:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-4" >
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4" >
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

If you had let's say 6 props, you would iterate 3 times over col-md-12:

```
<!-- 3 iterations here: -->
<div *ngFor="let i of iterations" class="col-md-12">
   <!-- Make sure not to go over objectProps size -->
   <div class="col-md-4" >
      {{objectProps[i*2]}}
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4" >
      {{objectProps[(i*2) + 1]}}
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Array *iterations* is defined based on objectProps length and number of col-md-4 children for each parent (eg. 6 objects, 2 for each col-md-12, gives 6/2=3 iterations), handy generator:

```
private renderIterations(arr, n): number[] {
    // arr - objectProps
    // n - number of props in each col-md-12

    let noOfParents = arr.length / n;
    let iterations = new Array(noOfParents);
    for (let q = 0; q < iterations.length; q++) {
        iterations[q] = q;
    }
    return iterations;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with outer ngFor without using ng-container.

**Ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
    objectProps: any[] = [
        { key: 1, type:'Text box'},
        { key: 2, type:'Text box'},
        { key: 3, type:'Text area'},
        { key: 4, type:'Text area'}
        ];

}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row col-md-12" *ngFor="let prop of objectProps;">
   <div class="col-md-4" >
       <input type="text"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4" >
       <textarea></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please see the how it render on the browser
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<ng-container>` to contain/populate html tags without introducing a new tag. For more information see [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/).

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let prop of objectProps; let index = index">
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div [ngSwitch]="prop.type" class="ticket_fields">
                 <div *ngSwitchCase="'Text box'">
                    <input [name]="prop.key" [id]="prop.key" type="text" ngModel #prop.key="ngModel" *ngIf="(prop.required ==1)" required>
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'Text area'">
                    <textarea name="{{prop.key}}" [id]="prop.key" ngModel #prop.key="ngModel" *ngIf="(prop.required ==1)" required></textarea>
                </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: While this might work, please add some exposition indicating why you've done it this way. Because right now it's simply a code-only answer which are considered low quality.

Comment: RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks for the suggestion. I thought the code is self-explanatory.